# Different clock rates from common clock famework?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How does different hardwares get different clock rates from common clock framework in linux, as in how physically different clock rates are obtained and who provides it physically?

Comment: Usually it is a RTC (Real time clock) which is a hardware based solution, which varies in accuracy, or software based solutions which synchronize with a central time keeping server.

Comment: It's too broad question. First of all there is a hardware that states what clock providers and consumers are present on certain platform. Then Linux kernel's clock framework is just a software abstraction on top of underlying hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a crystal oscillator is normally used to provide clock signal(source) to processor. A PLL in the processor generates the CPU's primary clock which will be of maximum rate. Different on-board peripherals/chips might required different clock rates for their operation. So, sub-multiple clocks shall be generated from the primary CPU clock which in-turn shall be used for various entities like memory, display, PCI/ISA interface, UART, timer etc.. Normally, there shall be dividers of various levels which should be configured via processor/hardware registers to match the clock  requirement of specific peripheral/entity. You may need to refer to the respective processor data sheet/hardware manual on the clock configuration for respective entities and accordingly derive from the primary clock rate.